# jQuery: Moving a row from one table to another and back again

Tags: jquery

I know this one's been asked quite a few times.  I've read over the others and haven't gotten a clear answer of what I need, so here's my version. :)

I have two tables... one is a DataTable (not that that really matters) with a list of properties (think homes).  I have another empty table nearby and when I click on a checkbox by a property row, I want it to move to the other table (aka "Selected Properties") while disappearing from the first table ("Available Properties").  Then I want the reverse to happen when you click on the checkbox in the new table.

I have the move from Available to Selected working fine:

```
$(".selectProperty").click(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();

    $(".selectedPropsTable tbody").append(tr);
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

    $(".selectedPropsTable .selectProperty").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
        $(this).removeClass("selectProperty");
        $(this).addClass("selectedProperty");
    });

});
```

But when I do mostly the same thing, it doesn't work:

```
$(".selectedProperty").on("click", function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();

    $(".searchTable tbody").append(tr);
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

    $(".searchTable .selectedProperty").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
        $(this).removeClass("selectedProperty");
        $(this).addClass("selectProperty");         
    });

});
```

Since I changed the classname of the checkbox during the move, I figured it would be fine to put a selector in to get its clicks, but even with .on() it's not working.  It won't even fire an alert("hi") so it's not working at all.

Sample table HTML.  First the "Available Properties" table:

```
<table class=".searchTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectProperty"></td>
```

Now the "Selected properties" table:

```
<table class=".selectedPropsTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectedProperty"></td>
```

Either I've typo'd something that I can't see, or I'm doing it wrong.  Help please? :)

Comment: Well thanks to whoever is downvoting this.  That's really helpful.  Truly.  #sarcasm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you know the different between `click()` vs `on('click')`, you can google this

your mistake is only write wrong syntax.

`$(elemen).click(function(){})` is same with `$(elemen).on('click', function(){});`

the correct one is:

`$(parent).on('event', 'yourelement', function(){})`

or this means

`$('.selectTable').on('click', '.selectProperty', function(){})`

here your code now

```js
$(function(){
 $("table").on('click', ".selectProperty, .selectedProperty", function() { 
  if($(this).hasClass('selectProperty'))
   var newTd= 'selectedProperty', newTbl='selectedPropsTable';
  else
   var newTd= 'selectProperty', newTbl='searchTable'; 
  $(this).prop('checked', false).attr('class', newTd);
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  $('table.'+newTbl).find("tbody").append(tr.clone()); 
  tr.remove(); 
 });
});
```

```html
<style>table{border:2px solid black;}</style>

<table class="searchTable"> 
 <tbody>
  <tr> <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectProperty">a1</td></tr>
  <tr> <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectProperty">a2</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table class="selectedPropsTable"> 
 <tbody>
  <tr> <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectedProperty">b1</td></tr>
  <tr> <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectedProperty">b2</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```